# Prevent Screen flickering during event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, screen, flicker

Hey guys, I know that in primitive versions of vb (as found in excel) there was a line that you could insert to prevent screens from flickering to and fro when it is trying to process something.

Application.screenupdating = false

I am currently using vb.net in Visual Studio 2008 but i was wondering if anyone knows the equivilent for this version. It doesnt recognise this call in VS 2008 using vb.net. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3):

Depends on control. Quite a lot of controls (e.g. ListView) have BeginUpdate and endUpdate methods that server that exact purpose.

```
list.BeginUpdate()
list.Items.Add(...)
list.Items.Add(...)
list.Items.Add(...)
...
list.EndUpdate()
```

Answer (score 3):

The SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout methods should do the trick.  SuspendLayout prevents a control/form from redrawing itself until you call the ResumeLayout method.

Answer (score 0):

Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Answer (score 0):

re: when it is trying to process something

you can disable the form